# Showing (head . init ) = head in Agda

Tags: theorem-proving, agda

I'm trying to prove a simple lemma in Agda, which I think is true.

> If a vector has more than two elements, taking its `head` following taking the `init` is the same as taking its `head` immediately.

I have formulated it as follows:

```
lem-headInit : ∀{l} (xs : Vec ℕ (suc (suc l)))
                    -> head (init xs) ≡ head xs
lem-headInit (x ∷ xs) = ?
```

Which gives me;

```
.l : ℕ
x  : ℕ
xs : Vec ℕ (suc .l)
------------------------------
Goal: head (init (x ∷ xs) | (initLast (x ∷ xs) | initLast xs)) ≡ x
```

as a response.

I do not entirely understand how to read the `(init (x ∷ xs) | (initLast (x ∷ xs) | initLast xs))` component. I suppose my questions are; is it possible, how and what does that term mean.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I do not entirely understand how to
>   read the `(init (x ∷ xs) | (initLast (x
>   ∷ xs) | initLast xs))` component. I
>   suppose my questions are; is it
>   possible, how and what does that term
>   mean.

This tells you that the value `init (x ∷ xs)` depends on the value of everything to the right of the `|`. When you prove something about in a function in Agda your proof will have to have the structure of the original definition.

In this case you have to case on the result of `initLast` because the definition of `initLast` does this before producing any results.

```
init : ∀ {a n} {A : Set a} → Vec A (1 + n) → Vec A n
init xs         with initLast xs
                --  ⇧  The first thing this definition does is case on this value
init .(ys ∷ʳ y) | (ys , y , refl) = ys
```

So here is how we write the lemma.

```
module inithead where

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Vec
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

lem-headInit : {A : Set} {n : ℕ} (xs : Vec A (2 + n))
             → head (init xs) ≡ head xs

lem-headInit (x ∷ xs) with initLast xs
lem-headInit (x ∷ .(ys ∷ʳ y)) | ys , y , refl = refl
```

I took the liberty of generalizing your lemma to `Vec A` since the lemma doesn't depend on the contents of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I've got this one by cheating and I'm hoping somebody has a better solution. I threw away all the extra information you get from `init` being defined in terms of `initLast` and created my own naive version.

```
initLazy : ∀{A l} → Vec A (suc l) → Vec A l
initLazy (x ∷ []) = []
initLazy (x ∷ (y ∷ ys)) = x ∷ (initLazy (y ∷ ys))
```

Now the lemma is trivial.

Any other offers?